# Estimating user percentile using mean, min, max and previous percentile for multiple tests

Tags: time-series, distributions, quantiles, z-score

I have a set of tests that a group of people take. The same people take all tests. I am given one person's score, along with the highest score, lowest score, and mean score and must estimate the person's percentile.

I understand that this does not contain enough information to define a distribution (beyond the basic triangular as I learnt in [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/467462)).

However, I'm also given the actual percentile of certain percentages at points in time. For example, after test 4, I might be told that a 68% score corresponds to the 23rd percentile.

I was thinking of assuming the distribution remains the same (triangular initially, whatever the previous distribution was after that), but I'm unsure how to define a distribution with this data. Furthermore, I thought I could do some minor adjustments to the distribution if needed, but I'm unsure how to check if it's needed or how much to shift it.

Any ideas or pointers would be helpful

Some example data:

```
+-----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+--------+
| test_name | usr_score  |    max     |    avg     |    min     | weight |
+-----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+--------+
| Test_1    | 0.94615385 | 1          | 0.92307692 | 0.65384615 |     26 |
| Test_2    | 0.71621622 | 0.95945946 | 0.79459459 | 0.74074074 |     37 |
| Test_3    | 1          | 1          | 0.92222222 | 0.7037037  |     27 |
| Test_4    | 0.85135135 | 0.97297297 | 0.85675676 | 0.66756757 |     37 |
| Test_5    | 0.83333333 | 1          | 0.76666667 | 0          |      6 |
| Test_6    | 1          | 1          | 0.92857143 | 0.66666667 |     21 |
+-----------+------------+------------+------------+------------+--------+
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are looking for.  It sounds given that Fred had a score of 80% on this test, what is his grade in the class for the semester.  Is that along the line of what you are looking for?

Comment: @EngrStudent - Right, the idea is to estimate a student's current percentile value given some percentage. The student is given his actual percentile at various points during the semester and can input that (I leave the details on how inputting works out), to better increase the accuracy of the results (so it doesn't default to triangular distribution).